# Number of id that has both positive and negative value for each date

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have below table, where 'dt' is the transaction date, 'id' is the customer id and 'amt' is the transaction amount. A positive 'amt' means saving and a negative 'amt' means spending. I'd like to find the number of id that has ever had both saving and spending for each date in a cumulative manner.

Whenever an id has first met the criteria of having both saving and spending on one date (one of them may occur on a previous date but the other must occur on this date), then the count of id for that date will increase by 1. If that id has further spending or saving on future dates, the count will not change any more.

```
CREATE TABLE trans (
  `dt` DATETIME,
  `id` INTEGER,
  `amt` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO trans
  (`dt`, `id`, `amt`)
VALUES
  ('2022-05-01', '001', '20'),
  ('2022-05-01', '001', '10'),
  ('2022-05-02', '002', '-20'),
  ('2022-05-02', '001', '-10'),
  ('2022-05-03', '002', '10'),
  ('2022-05-03', '003', '8'),
  ('2022-05-04', '002', '5'),
  ('2022-05-05', '003', '-4'),
  ('2022-05-06', '003', '-1');
```

In this example, on 2022-05-01 id 001 has two saving but no spending, hence number of id is 0. On 2022-05-02 id 001 has a spending, now id 001 has both saving and spending, so number of id is 1. Same for the following dates. The desired output is:

| dt | num |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 0 |
| 2022-05-02 | 1 |
| 2022-05-03 | 2 |
| 2022-05-04 | 2 |
| 2022-05-05 | 3 |
| 2022-05-06 | 3 |

I managed to come up with quite a complex query with multiple window functions, but I just want to see if there is any simpler method for this? I'm using MySQL v8.0

```
select t7.dt, first_value(num) over(partition by t7.val order by t7.dt asc) as num from(
select *, sum(case when num is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by dt asc) as val from(
select distinct t5.dt, num from(
select dt, sum(flag) over(order by dt asc) as num from(
select dt, case when sum(amt_type) over(partition by id order by dt asc)=0 then 1 else 0 end as flag from(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id, amt_type order by dt asc) rnk from (
select *, case when amt>0 then 1 else -1 end as amt_type from
trans where amt<>0) t1) t2
where rnk=1) t3) t4
right join trans t5 on
t4.dt=t5.dt) t6) t7
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your aggregation logic for counting saving and spending is not clear.  Please explain the rules more clearly.

Comment: Hi Tim I have updated my description. Hope it’s clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first aggregate days for each id and divide spending and savings in different columns, then you need to sum up, for each date, all previous transactions, so you can finally count them.

```
;with
dx as(
    select dt, id
        , sum(iif(amt>0, amt, 0)) Savings
        , sum(iif(amt<0, amt, 0)) Spendings
    from trans
    group by dt, id
),
dd as (
    select d1.dt, d1.id
        , sum(d2.Savings) Savings
        , sum(d2.Spendings) Spendings
    from dx d1
    join dx d2 on d1.dt >= d2.dt and d1.id = d2.id
    group by d1.dt, d1.id
    having sum(d2.Savings) <>0 and sum(d2.Spendings) <>0
)
select d.dt, count(distinct dd.id) n
from d
left join dd on d.dt >= dd.dt
group by d.dt
order by 1
```